# How can I get the current amount of daylight given only the local date/time? (like flux does)

Tags: javascript, datetime, dst, flux

My plan is to give a slight tint to a web page based on the current local time (from javascript). I don't need something as specific as current lumens or anything, but I'd like to get the approximate time for peak sunlight, sunrise, sunset, and mid-night +-2 hours or so. I realize the exact times would vary greatly based on latitude & longitude and also timezone data, which I could potentially have access to. But to start off, I was wondering if there were just a formula for something like [northern] hemisphere and current local time.

How does [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) do it?

**Update 1:** Most of my searches have just returned daylight savings related info, which isn't very helpful. I did find this JS: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/main.js (from here http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/) but it is laden with unexplained magic constants. For example:

```
function calcGeomMeanLongSun(t)
{
  var L0 = 280.46646 + t * (36000.76983 + t*(0.0003032))
  while(L0 > 360.0)
  {
    L0 -= 360.0
  }
  while(L0 < 0.0)
  {
    L0 += 360.0
  }
  return L0     // in degrees
}

function calcGeomMeanAnomalySun(t)
{
  var M = 357.52911 + t * (35999.05029 - 0.0001537 * t);
  return M;     // in degrees
}

function calcEccentricityEarthOrbit(t)
{
  var e = 0.016708634 - t * (0.000042037 + 0.0000001267 * t);
  return e;     // unitless
}
```

**Update 2:** I think the "cost" of determining a locale of the user via gps or whatever is too great (especially since this is purely for cosmetic reasons and serves no other functional purpose), so I'm probably just going to stick with the 12am-6am-12pm-6pm cycle of whatever the local time is via javascript.

**Update 3:** I just went with a slightly modified sine-wave with a small preference towards day-time:

```
  var x, fx, hour,
  // starting hsl value for midnight:
      h = 220, 
      s = 42, 
      l = 75;

  for (hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
    // 0 for midnight, up to 12 for noon
    x = 12 - Math.abs(hour - 12);

    // 0.0 to 1.0
    fx = x / 12;
    // factor of pi, shift x axis by 1 half pi
    fx = (Math.PI * (fx - (1 / 2)));
    // sine function
    fx = Math.sin(fx);
    // +1 to start at 0, take half to max out at one
    fx = (fx + 1) / 2;
    // skew the values just slightly for daytime
    fx = Math.pow(fx, 0.75);
    // change range back to top out at 12
    fx = fx * 12;

    // base of 220 degrees, 18.25 provided a nice color rage from bluish to yellowish
    h = Math.floor((220 + (18.25 * fx)));
    // rotate on 360 degrees
    while (h >= 360) { 
      h = h - 360; 
    }

    // base of 42% saturated, multiplied x for a linear slope up to 100%
    s = Math.floor(42 + (5.5 * x));
    // 100 max
    if (s > 100) {
      s = 100; 
    }

    // base of 75% lightness, 1.85 factor was a nice linear slope stopping short of 100%
    l = Math.floor(75 + (1.85 * x));
    // 100 max
    if (l > 100) {
      l = 100; 
    }


    // "style='background-color: hsl(" + h + ", " + s + "%, " + l + "%);'"
  }
```

[Here it is on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bicep/5). I may play around with getting the actual amount in the future, but this gets me close enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Is not this equation from Wikipedia enough:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation

There is no magic in it, just a bit of math.

Or do you need something more?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I knew that there must have been an explanation somewhere. There are still some unexplained constants in those equations though. I'd like to figure out what they represent.